# HTML/CSS table with fixed width column (and scroll if overflowing content)

Tags: html, css, html-table, grid

I have an HTML table with one or multiple fixed-width columns.
Sometimes the content of such a column exceeds the column width and I would like to have a scrollbar at the bottom of the table column.

- I would like to maintain the same semantic HTML structure and not have duplicate tables or multiple iterations.
- I would like to have as little JavaScript as possible
- I can turn this into a CSS Grid or Flexbox if that is possible there (but haven't used that before)

I've noticed that is HTML there is a `colgroup` and it looks like I can set the `width` and other CSS properties, but not `overflow`.

```html
<table class="table">
  <colgroup>
    <col class="table-colgroup table-colgroup--first">
    <col class="table-colgroup table-colgroup--second">
    <col class="table-colgroup table-colgroup--third">
  </colgroup>
  <tr class="table-row">
    <td class="table-cell table-cell--first">
      <p>First</p>
    </td>
    <td class="table-cell table-cell--second">
      <p>Second long column item that should have scroll 1</p>
    </td>
    <td class="table-cell table-cell--third">
      <p>Last column item</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-row">
    <td class="table-cell table-cell--first">
      <p>First</p>
    </td>
    <td class="table-cell table-cell--second">
      <p>Second long column item that should have scroll 2</p>
    </td>
    <td class="table-cell table-cell--third">
      <p>Last column item</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-row">
    <td class="table-cell table-cell--first">
      <p>First</p>
    </td>
    <td class="table-cell table-cell--second">
      <p>Second long column item that should have scroll 3</p>
    </td>
    <td class="table-cell table-cell--third">
      <p>Last column item</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-row">
    <td class="table-cell table-cell--first">
      <p>First</p>
    </td>
    <td class="table-cell table-cell--second">
      <p>Second long column item that should have scroll 4</p>
    </td>
    <td class="table-cell table-cell--third">
      <p>Last column item</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-row">
    <td class="table-cell table-cell--first">
      <p>First</p>
    </td>
    <td class="table-cell table-cell--second">
      <p>Second long column item that should have scroll 5</p>
    </td>
    <td class="table-cell table-cell--third">
      <p>Last column item</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-row">
    <td class="table-cell table-cell--first">
      <p>First</p>
    </td>
    <td class="table-cell table-cell--second">
      <p>Second long column item that should have scroll 6</p>
    </td>
    <td class="table-cell table-cell--third">
      <p>Last column item</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```css
.table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-row {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px yellowgreen;
}

.table-cell {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px blue;
}

.table-colgroup--first {
  background: palegoldenrod;
}

.table-colgroup--second {
  background: paleturquoise;
  /*
   * I would like to pass the width of the column here
   */
  width: 50px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.table-colgroup--third {
  background: palegreen;
} 

/* This is intentionally long so that a scrollbar appears somewhere */
.table-cell--second p {
  width: 900px;
  background: #666;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Please check my Codepen example with what I've tried: [Code sample](https://codepen.io/anything/pen/Zdgeam)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap the content of the table cells in a div with overflow-x auto and this will trigger the scroll whenever the content of the td is bigger than the cell.

```
<td><div style="overflow-x: 'scroll'"><p>long line here</p></div>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an [explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -3):

Before table tag , take a parent div and put style overflow-x:auto;

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
     enter code here
     enter code here
   </table>
</div>
.table-responsive{
overflow-x:auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Jay! Not sure if you read the full description of the question: I want to overflow only on that column, not the whole table. This looks to me like it ads the overflow on the full table.